How do you mix 1d and 2d variables in a pandas dataframe?
I am working with a bucketload of data that has the form:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

lat = np.array([80.589, 80.592, 80.595])
lon = np.array([50.268, 50.264, 50.260])
wav = np.array([[486, 605, 666, 821, 777,  719],
                [ 65,  60,  68,  67,  72,   64],
                [866, 946, 882, 855, 999, 1195]])
print("lat shape:",lat.shape)
print("lon shape:",lon.shape)
print("wav shape:",wav.shape)

# lat shape: (3,)
# lon shape: (3,)
# wav shape: (3, 6)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Lon': lon,
    'Lat': lat,
    'Wav': wav})

which gives the error "ValueError: Per-column arrays must each be 1-dimensional"
I can work around this by converting the guts of wav to a string and back again when I need it, but that is Ugly Gross, and I would like to find the proper way to handle mix dimension arrays in a pandas dataframe.
Desired result:
print(df.head(1))

      Lon     Lat    Wav
0  50.268  80.589    [486, 605, 666, 821, 777,  719]


Just add .tolist() to wav -> wav.tolist()

Pandas doesn't consider a numpy array as an iterable in this case. You have to explicitly convert your numpy array to a list (with tolist):
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Lon': lon,
    'Lat': lat,
    'Wav': wav.tolist(),
})

Output:
      Lon     Lat                              Wav
0  50.268  80.589   [486, 605, 666, 821, 777, 719]
1  50.264  80.592         [65, 60, 68, 67, 72, 64]
2  50.260  80.595  [866, 946, 882, 855, 999, 1195]


both this and the one below work.  I am sellecting this as the answer as it is a touch more elligant.

Cannot deny it !

How about using a list of lists ?
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Lon': lon,
    'Lat': lat,
    'Wav': [list(wav_row) for wav_row in wav]
})



This worked!  I will have to convert the wavforme data later to a numpy array, but this solves the problem.

@EBo could you explain your use case? If you have to convert it back to numpy array why not keeping a numpy array in the first place and avoid inserting it in the DataFrame?

@mozway, sure.I am working with CryoSat-2 radar data - which has Latitude, Longitude, and Waveform data (and more).  Most of the data is has a single element per lat/lon location -- except for the waveform.  The waveform has 256 elements for each lat/lon location.  Now when I create a pandas dataframe most data is a 1-d array, but waveform is 2-d, and it keeps triggering the errors above.  If there is a trick to keep it as an np.ndarray (or np.matrix) great, but keeping it as a list until I have to process it is better than handling the waveform separately.

@EBo ok, but what do you do after you created the DataFrame? Do you filter rows, reorder them? I'm fairly sure that you could avoid using a list.

@mozway, for more context we are working with data from 2 or 3 different satellites, and there are literally millions of points can be filtered by time, distance, quality, and more.  I too was thinking that there should be a way to set up the dataframe with a 2-d variable without using lists, but even if I have to convert at the end, having everything in a single dataframe allows me to leverage dask.distributed and other tools to scale up.

Fair enough. In this case the only way this could work is if you can maintain the original indices and are not using the waveform values during filtering. Thanks for giving your use case ;)
